# Pdfminer parsing documents with layout and bbox

Tags: python, pdfminer

I am using pdfminer to parse certain types of pdf's (only for text) like degree certificates etc. Hence for a particular institution these remains same and could vary across different institutions.

Since, I am new to this one I would appreciate if I could get any ideas on how to parse different objects in layout (like - registration number). What are different ways of parsing or manipulating bounding boxes or whatever curves etc.

This might be broad but considering the documentation of pdfminer it seems it would help further users. Below is the sample code I started with :-

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox, LTTextLine, LTImage, LTFigure
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.converter import HTMLConverter
from io import StringIO

def get_layouts(pdf_doc):
    fp = open(pdf_doc, 'rb')
    parser = PDFParser(fp)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    parser.set_document(doc)
    #print (doc.catalog)
    try:
        outlines = doc.get_outlines()
        for (level, title, dest, a, se) in outlines:
            print (' ' * level, title)
    except PDFNoOutlines:
        pass

    if not doc.is_extractable:
        raise PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    text = ''
    for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        layout = device.get_result()
        for lt_obj in layout:
            if isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextBox) or isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextLine):
                text += lt_obj.get_text()
        break
    return text
```

Answer (score 1):

If the necessary information is in the exact same location on each record, you can use the x and y coordinates of each LTTextContainer (LTTextContainer.x0, LTTextContainer.x1, LTTextContainer.y0, LTTextContainer.y1) to find out where an LTTextContainer is. This probably wouldn't work if the different schools had different formats for their certificates, though.